# Replace only selected fields using binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm building simple twitter clone in Spring MVC. I want to provide edit functionality to posted messages.

Message domain object looks like this (simplified)

```
public class Message {
    long id;
    String text;
    Date date;
    User user;
}
```

I created jps form

```
    <form:form action="edit" method="post" modelAttribute="message">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="text">Message: </label></td>
                <td><form:textarea path="text" id="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

and added those method in controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showEditMessage(@RequestParam long id, Model model) {
        Message message = messageService.findMessage(id);
        if (message == null) {
            return "404";
        }
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        return "users/editMessage";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editMessage(@Valid @ModelAttribute Message message, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "/users/editMessage";
        }

        messageService.updateMessage(message);
        return "/users/editMessage";
    }
```

The problem is that the Message received in editMessage() contains only text field. I assume that this is expected behaviour. Can it be configured to replace fields that are only in jsp form?

I know this is only one field and I could just use @RequestParam String message, but sooner or later I will face similar problem with more than just one field.

I also have side question.
Are attributes added in showEditMessage() are passed to editMessage() method? I tried to add "id" attribute in first method, but I couldn't retrive it using "@RequestParam long id" in second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@SessionAttributes("message")
```

On top of controller class solved it.